# HoloLens spatial mapping.SpatialSurfaceMesh update problem. C++/winrt

Tags: hololens, c++-winrt, hololens-emulator

im working on the spatial mapping processing for my HoloLens project.

Somehow calling "SpatialSurfaceMesh::TryComputeLatestMeshAsync" keeps returning the same mesh data overtime.
Is there another process involved updating the observer?

```cpp
void SpatialMapping::AddOrUpdateSurface(winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::SpatialCoordinateSystem const& coordinateSystem)
{
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::Surfaces;

    SpatialBoundingBox axisAlignedBoundingBox =
    {
        {  0.f,  0.f, 0.f },
        { 50.f, 50.f, 50.f },
    };
    SpatialBoundingVolume bounds = SpatialBoundingVolume::FromBox(coordinateSystem, axisAlignedBoundingBox);
    m_surfaceObserver.SetBoundingVolume(bounds);

    m_surfaceObserver.ObservedSurfacesChanged(
        winrt::Windows::Foundation::TypedEventHandler
        <SpatialSurfaceObserver, winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable>
        ({ this, &SpatialMapping::Observer_ObservedSurfacesChanged })
    );
}

void SpatialMapping::Observer_ObservedSurfacesChanged(winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::Surfaces::SpatialSurfaceObserver const& sender
    , winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& object)
{
    {
        using namespace winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::Surfaces;

        const auto mapContainingSurfaceCollection = sender.GetObservedSurfaces();

        // Process surface adds and updates?.
        for (const auto& pair : mapContainingSurfaceCollection)
        {
            auto id = pair.Key();
            auto info = pair.Value();
            InsertAsync(id, info);
        }
    }
}

Concurrency::task<void> SpatialMapping::InsertAsync(winrt::guid  /*const&*/ id, winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::Surfaces::SpatialSurfaceInfo  /*const&*/ newSurfaceInfo)
{
    using namespace winrt::Windows::Perception::Spatial::Surfaces;

    return concurrency::create_task([this, id, newSurfaceInfo]
        {
            const auto surfaceMesh = newSurfaceInfo.TryComputeLatestMeshAsync(m_maxTrianglesPerCubicMeter, m_surfaceMeshOptions).get();
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_meshCollectionLock);
            m_updatedSurfaces.emplace(id, surfaceMesh);
        });

}
```

[Generation works, Update does not](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ES3jF.png)

Manuel attempt same problem:

```cpp
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction SpatialMapping::CollectSurfacesManuel()
{
    const auto mapContainingSurfaceCollection = m_surfaceObserver.GetObservedSurfaces();
    for (const auto& pair : mapContainingSurfaceCollection)
    {
        auto id = pair.Key();
        auto info = pair.Value();
        auto mesh{ co_await info.TryComputeLatestMeshAsync(m_maxTrianglesPerCubicMeter, m_surfaceMeshOptions) };
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m_meshCollectionLock);
            m_updatedSurfaces.emplace(id, mesh);
        }
    }
}
```

MVCE:

1. Create a New Project with the template
   "Holographic DirectX 11 App (UWP) C++/WinRT)"
2. Add the files:
   https://github.com/lpnxDX/HL_MVCE_SpatialSurfaceMeshUpdateProblem.git
3. Replace m_main in AppView.h

Comment: Passing values by const ref into asynchronous operations is certainly asking for trouble. You should be passing by value instead. That may or may not be related to the issue you observed.

Comment: Makes no difference.

Answer (score 0):

We did some research and have some thoughts about your question right now, let me explain the findings

1. Has your Observer_ObservedSurfacesChanged method triggered exactly? Adding output statements or breakpoints can help you check it. Since SurfaceObserver should be always available, usually we need to check the availability of surfaceObserver in each frame and recreate a new one when necessary, sample code snippt please see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/HolographicSpatialMapping/cpp/HolographicSpatialMappingMain.cpp#L219).
2. Have you set m_surfaceMeshOptions? It is not visible in the code you posted. If it is missing, you can configure it with the following statement:

   > surfaceMeshOptions-> IncludeVertexNormals = true;
3. Microsoft provided the [Holographic spatial mapping sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HolographicSpatialMapping), shows how to acquire spatial mapping data from Windows Perception in real-time. it is similar to your needs, to narrow down issue if it's an issue with your code, please try to check and run this example on your device
4. If after the above steps, you still can't solve the problem, could you provide an
   [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can locate the issue or find a solution? Be careful to remove any privacy-related or other business function codes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer

1. Observer_ObservedSurfacesChanged triggers only when binding (1x)

2. yes, mesh generation is working. Updating is the problem.

3. Example is written in c++/cx. Afterall it can be a bug in c++/winrt.

4. MVCE:

1. Create a New Project with the template

"Holographic DirectX 11 App (UWP) C++/WinRT)"

2. Add the files:

https://github.com/lpnxDX/HL_MVCE_SpatialSurfaceMeshUpdateProblem.git

3. Replace m_main in AppView.h

Answer (score 0):

Your code has the following problems:

1. TryComputeLatestMeshAsync should be called from Observer_ObservedSurfacesChanged not from concurrency::create_task
2. TryComputeLatestMeshAsync return mesh with matrix, vertices and indices. Indices should be stored to a safe location at the first run, they don't change later. Vertices and matrix should copied as they returns. You shouldn't save the mesh itself, because its data updates from various threads.
3. ObservedSurfacesChanged shouldn't be called every frame. This is long running function.

Maybe it has something more. I would recommend to start from the sample mentioned earlier.